# applying Javascript on current page using bookmark bar

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I am trying to apply JavaScript on the page displayed on the browser using the bookmark bar, just like method explained in this link :
https://www.tecdrop.com/iseepass/

I want to hide something in the page, and I tried this code

```
javascript:(function(){
document.getElementsById("someTable").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsById("someTable").style.visibility = 'hidden';
})();
```

but this did not work.

BTW: object with ID someTable exist in the page I tried with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsById` doesn't exists. It's `getElementById` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed this :)